# WP-Widget, constructor {Versión 5.8 de Wordpress y versión 8 de PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, constructor

Muy buenas a todos/as,

Tengo un problema con mi página de Wordpress, ya que después de actualizar a la última versión de PHP, no me carga la página y me salta el siguiente error en pantalla:

**Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function WP_Widget::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-includes\class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 61 and at least 2 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-includes\class-wp-widget.php:162 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-includes\class-wp-widget-factory.php(61): WP_Widget->__construct() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-includes\widgets.php(115): WP_Widget_Factory->register('catchbox_adwidg...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-content\themes\catch-box.1.4\catch-box\functions.php(428): register_widget('catchbox_adwidg...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(303): catchbox_widgets_init('') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-includes\plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-includes\widgets.php(1809): do_action('widgets_init') #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(303): wp_widgets_init('') #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-includes\plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-settings.php(578): do_action('init') #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-config.php(90): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-load.php(50): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\index.php(17): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #15 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor-juntas\wp-includes\class-wp-widget.php on line 162**

He estado indagando un poco en la web, pero lo cierto es que a la hora de intentar solucionarlo no doy con la tecla y estoy bastante perdido con este fallo.

Les dejo el extracto de código:

```js
public function __construct( $id_base, $name, $widget_options = array(), $control_options = array() ) {
        if ( ! empty( $id_base ) ) {
            $id_base = strtolower( $id_base );
        } else {
            $id_base = preg_replace( '/(wp_)?widget_/', '', strtolower( get_class( $this ) ) );
        }

        $this->id_base         = $id_base;
        $this->name            = $name;
        $this->option_name     = 'widget_' . $this->id_base;
        $this->widget_options  = wp_parse_args(
            $widget_options,
            array(
                'classname'                   => str_replace( '\\', '_', $this->option_name ),
                'customize_selective_refresh' => false,
            )
        );
        $this->control_options = wp_parse_args( $control_options, array( 'id_base' => $this->id_base ) );
    }
```

Imagino que tendré que cambiar bastantes cosillas que no serán compatibles con esta nueva versión.

¿Alguien me podría decir cómo solucionarlo por favor?

Comment: Muchas veces los errores los causa un plugin, has lo siguiente, ve a wp-content/plugins, renombra la carpeta a plugins-old o el nombre que desees y regresa a tu wordpress, verifica si el error se soluciono, de ser asi, algun plugin es el que lo esta causando, si no es asi, prueba a activar un tema por default de wordpress, puedes cambiarlo desde la db, aunque no recuerdo el nombre de la tabla, si se arregla, posiblemente sea el tema actual, si no es el tema o los plugins entonces si es wordpress el que lo causa, habria que testear el porque, revisa el error.log y activa el wp debug

Comment: Si es un plugin, ve activando uno a uno hasta encontrarlo, si lo encuentras, actualizalo o reportalo al desarrollador o bien, intenta solucionarlo tu mismo, en el error.log o el wp-debug deberia de aparecer si es asi y guiarte mas o menos en donde esta el error, lo mismo si es el tema, de no ser ninguno de estos dos entonces tendrias que ver la version de php, pasala a la ultima version, puede que sea eso

Comment: ¿Estás usando o tienes instalado el tema [Catch Box](https://es.wordpress.org/themes/catch-box/) de Wordpress? ¿Está todo actuaizado en tu Wordpress (versión de WP, temas, plugins)?

Comment: Muy buenos días, muchas gracias a ambos por responder la consulta. Ahora mismo tiene la última versión de Wordpress (5.8) y la última versión de PHP (8). Con respecto al propio tema, plugins y demás, está todo actualizado, a falta de un plugin que si no recuerdo mal, no se puede actualizar más. La verdad es que no sé muy bien qué hacer, ya que he hecho todas las comprobaciones anteriormente comentadas y me sigue pasando lo mismo...

Comment: Si la clase está instanciada el registro de un widget toma un sólo parámetro que es la clase . La versión 1.4 del theme ( `\themes\catch-box.1.4\catch-box\functions.php(428)` ) asume que la clase está instanciada antes del `register_widget`
https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/catch-box/1.4/functions.php , el require está dentro de la función `catchbox_setup` que puede estar siendo reemplazada en un child theme. La versión 4.8.9 tiene la clase en el mismo include https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/catch-box/4.8.9/inc/widgets.php y éste se carga independientemente de la función `catchbox_setup`.